Multiple electromagnets and limiting current
I got this circuit

Im going to have about 20 electromagnets. My powersupply is set to deliver max 100mA and 24volt. Since Im going to drive 20 of these sometimes on the same time with pwm I guess that in most extreme scenario all of them are turned on at the same time I need
Total Current (if all magnets on)=100mA×20=2000mA=2A

They are only turned on in pulses though about 50ms and 80ms in between.
However If I use a powersupply that delivers 24 volt and 2ampere I need to limit the current on each electromagnet so it wont use all 2 ampere.
Here are some ideas how to do this:
I can do this with a resistor. If the goal is 0.1A R = 0.1A / 24V = 240 ohm. But the effect will be pretty big I guess and they will be warm so probably not the best approach?
Second approach could be to use PWM. I have tried as for example increasing the max current to 2A and set     analogWrite(currentPin, 70);
this seem to work better and it doesnt generate as much heat and the magnet seem to be as strong at least when trying just with one. So my question is are there any disadevantages with this approach or another better approach driving multiple electromagnets avoiding overheating.

These numbers don't really make sense together. Is the 100mA limit set by your power supply or the resistance of the electromagnets? If it set by the power supply then what is the reason you need to limit them to 100mA when connected to a larger supply? Depending on the application, a somewhat more complex hit and hold scheme might be useful.

What do you mean, with "in serie"? What for you feed PWM to the electromagnets? Currently it looks like you want  to drive 20 electromagnets separately. PS: Study basics of inductances, e. g. formula I = U * t / L ... PS2: D1 has wrong polarity

You will need to know the resistance and inductance of a coil, because that will constrain switching rates, and figure in the calculations for other resistances and such.

Is the 100mA limit set by your power supply or the resistance of the electromagnets? yes. set by powersupply Currently it looks like you want to drive 20 electromagnets separately. yes that is the case. D1 has wrong polarity  true. You will need to know the resistance and inductance of a coil, it is about 10 ohm.

Did you take any notice of the answer I gave to your previous question on this subject: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=chessboard <-- in particular the bit about the diode being the wrong way round.

A 100mA load draws 100mA from a power supply that can provide up to 2A for 20 100mA loads.  Basic thing how loads and supplies work. Your computer also draws 100W from mains socket even if there is 3000W available before fuse blows, or thousands of kilowatts available from the power transformer and power plant. You don't need to limit the current.
However there are other issues in your circuit.
The FET barely turns on at 3.3V from MCU. It should work for small load of 100mA, but the FET is rated for tens of amps and to switch that it should be used with more than 3.3V.
The diode will also short your supply to ground when you activate the transistor. It's the wrong way around.
The connector reads 12V but you talk about 24V. It does not matter but still there is a discrepancy.
